# Is there a way for a user to tell if their Android device is encrypted or not?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption

There is a semi-relevant thread on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640708/check-if-android-filesystem-is-encrypted
that explains how a developer would determine if full-disk encryption is enabled, but is there an easy way for a user to know? I tried encrypting (I'm on 4.4.2) and it seemed to fail at some point but did not throw an error, just dropped me back to the homescreen at a certain point.

Comment: That's not conclusive (as you said), you can set a PIN without encryption

Comment: I have a Galaxy S6 that I attempted to encrypt, I started the process and took a shower. When I came back to check the results I could not tell if it was successful. The only difference is that there is no longer a choice to encrypt. That does not conclusively indicate that the phone is encrypted.

Answer (score 13):

**On Oreo 8.0.0**

Settings → Security & Location → Encryption & Credentials & it shows `phone encrypted`

**Better method**

Using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) command `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state` ( works on unrooted devices also) returns `encrypted` or `unencrypted`

Output examples

- Oreo ( Unrooted, encrypted)

> Vostro1510 ~ $ adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state
>
> encrypted

- Marshmallow ( Rooted, unencrypted)

> Vostro1510 ~ $ adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state
>
> unencrypted

**[Source - Adb command to check if the device is encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45409854)**

Note : Original question refers to Full Disk Encryption which has been replaced by File encryption from Nougat onwards. See [this for details](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/)

**Edit** Instead of `adb` you can install [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) and type `getprop ro.crypto.state` to get the result - works on unrooted device also

Comment: +1. Is there a way to know if the device uses full-disk encryption or file based encryption?

Comment: @Firelord Thanks. Yes, we have an answer here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195713

Comment: You call it "Better method". Unfortunately I don't know how many people have adb installed or not. I guess (but don't) know that most devices don't have adb.

Comment: @guettli guess you missed the app alternative towards the end of the answer

Answer (score 8):

Same place where you start the encryption:

In (I am on 4.3) `Settings -> Options -> Security`,
the first entry will report the status and offer decrypt (if encrypted)
or encrypt (if not).

Comment: I could be wrong but isn't there a difference between FDE and system encryption? I think the one you mention is only system level.

Answer (score 4):

If your phone came with Android 5 or above, the storage is encrypted by default. You can verify this by going into `Settings` > `Security & lock screen` > `Encryption & credentials`. It should say *Encrypt phone - encrypted* and it won't allow you to turn it off.

Hovewer, the safety of the encryption depends on several factors. Most importantly, you should be using a strong password. PIN codes can be brute forced easily - Android allows you to try 5 different passwords every 30 seconds. That means brute forcing a 4 digit PIN takes less than 17 hours.

Another factor is whether you have the bootloader unlocked and what kind of encryption your phone uses.

### File-based encryption

*Android 10+, some devices with Android 7 - 9.*

Android with FBE enabled encrypts the master key by a combination of the device key and your PIN/password. A device like this is NOT decryptable without your password even if one can run arbitrary code* on the device.

You can quickly verify if your phone is using FBE by restarting it. If it asks for PIN/password with a default-themed keyboard, it's using FBE.

A more reliable way is running `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.type`. You'll get the response `file` for FBE.

### Full-disk encryption

*Android 4.4 - 6, some devices with Android 7 - 9.*

The master key is encrypted using only the device key by default. If you can run any code* on the device, your data is as good as unencrypted. To encrypt the master key with your PIN or password, you need to enable "secure startup" (`Settings` > `Security & location` > `Screen lock` > `PIN` or `Password` and tap `Yes` when it asks if you want to use Secure start-up). That makes the master key encrypted with the device key AND your PIN/password.

If you get a black screen with a prompt "To start Android, enter your PIN/password", then your phone is using the secure start-up. If it boots normally and asks for PIN/password with your customized keyboard, your phone is NOT using the secure start-up.

You can check if the device is using FDE by running `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.type`. You'll get the response `block` for FDE.

---

* you can run arbitrary code if the bootloader is unlocked, the device manufacturer (or possibly a very determined hacker) can likely do this even with bootloader locked

Read more about Android encryption here: https://source.android.com/security/encryption/

Comment: @alecxs You can verify this by launching TWRP on an Android <=9 device and being able to read the contents of the device without entering a password/PIN. If the key was encrypted, this would be impossible. What would it be encrypted with anyway? I tested this on a Mi A1 (tissot) when "secure start-up" was not enabled.

Comment: Using the passphrase "default_password" is as good as having an unencrypted key, but I'll change the wording to reflect that.

Comment: some weird exception (forced by chinese government?) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241934

Answer (score 0):

Try changeing default storage to SD Card

`Settings -> Memory -> Default Location -> SD Card`

if your phone is encrypted than you'll get a warning stating that internal memory is encrypted. Of course its only a hint, not a proof.

My P9 Lite (Android 7) behaves like that, and this is consistent with [user guide](http://download-c1.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=80267&version=318949&siteCode=ke) page 193

> Full-disk encryption |  All data on the memory chipset is
>   automatically encrypted