# Does encrypting an Android phone also encrypt old, deleted files?

Tags: internal-storage, encryption

I'm going to be selling my phone soon. The advice seems to be to encrypt it then performs a Factory Reset. But does the ​​whole ​​internal memory get encrypted, or just the current, visible files? If so, surely that leaves old, deleted files recoverable. ​​​​​​

Comment: That depends if a full disk encryption (FDE) or a file based encryption (FBE) is used. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195713.

Comment: The problem is it's a 5.0 phone updated to 6.0. So I'm unsure. I'll be doing several 100% memory overwrites, along with Factory Resets and encryptions, just to be sure.

Comment: How do you do "100% memory overwrites"? Note that your device may have multiple partitions. Therefore you have to overwrite each of it that contains user data. Some partitions should not be overwritten as they don't contain user data and are required (e.g. on some Samsung devices there are partitions containing IMEI and other related stuff, without this partition the mobile network will not work.