# Android 9 Pie says 'encrypted', but phone can receive calls after reboot (before entering screen lock password)?

Tags: encryption

I have a new Optus branded ZTE phone (Android 9 Pie). I added a screen lock password. Apparently it is now automatically encrypted -

Settings / Security & location / Advanced / Encryption & credentials / Encrypt phone = "encrypted"

When I reboot the phone, I had expected for the phone to request my password before it got to my home screen (my older phone did this). However, to my surprise, upon reboot... the phone boots to the home screen. How can it know what my home screen looks like before I even enter the password?

In addition, it can receive calls? Further, if I swipe down and click 'Screenshot'... it will perform the screenshot and add it to Local / Phone / Pictures / Screenshots

What am I missing?

Comment: That's how File Based Encryption (FBE) works. What you are expecting is Full Disk Encryption (FDE), being replaced with FBE by most of the OEMs.

Comment: To further add to what @IrfanLatif said, see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/38632977

Comment: Also see this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195713/131553

Comment: @ajjwjajatt please use comments or edit your question to add further details. // Does your screenshot persist after you unlock the screen? If so, your OEM encrypted the internal SD card directory (`/data/media`) as Device Encrypted (DE), not Credential Encrypted (CE), though that doesn't make much sense. You need a rooted phone to fully explore the details of encryption.

Comment: +1 for making your own thoughs about