# Does GrapheneOS's Android 10-based releases use FDE (Full Disk Encryption)?

Tags: security, encryption, android-10, disk-encryption, password-protection

According to the [ASOP documentation](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk), it is no longer possible to use FDE and the user is forced to use File-Based Encryption

> Note: Devices running Android 7.0–9 support full-disk encryption. New devices running Android 10 and higher must use [file-based encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based).

Though I understand the argument for convenience (morning alarms, updates, etc), there are several strong use-cases where it's better to have a FDE with a very long passphrase -- consider journalists, activists, political prisoners, etc crossing borders with oppressive governments. It's better to just turn the device off and rely on FDE to protect absolutely everything in these situations.

I see that [GraphoneOS's FAQ page](https://grapheneos.org/faq#encryption) talks about FDE and also Android 10, but doesn't directly answer this question.

Do the GraphoneOS releases that are based on Android 10 still use FDE? If so, how?

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239114/how-to-use-fde-in-android-10-full-disk-encryption

Comment: lot Android 10 devices still running FDE, the quoted google statement is irrelevant. which encryption type is used depends on device, not OS

Comment: @alecxs can you name one device that runs Android 10 and uses FDE?

Comment: Mi5, Poco F1, Galaxy S9+ (and lot more)

Comment: They don't run Android 10+

Comment: download stock ROM for [star2lte](https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-s9-plus/firmware/SM-G965F/DBT/download/G965FXXU9ETF5/344923) and check */vendor/etc/fstab.samsungexynos9810* yourself. i have two [Poco F1](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/beryllium) and i know it for sure

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239114/how-to-use-fde-in-android-10-full-disk-encryption#comment317406_239114 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233129 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230892

Comment: GrapheneOS clearly mention [metadata](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/metadata) encryption which is FBE (not FDE) with additional `keydirectory=` in fstab (previously location for FDE crypto footer) for example default since Android 9 on [One Plus 7](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_oneplus_guacamole/blob/android-9.0/recovery/root/etc/twrp.fstab)