Full Android 13 backup
I have a Samsung S9 phone running lineageos with root
I want to make a full backup of apps, config, SMS, etc. (Basically a byte-to-byte image of the disk).
This is to wipe it and install only the essentials again (I'm running low on storage, and ram including swap, to start clean from scratch.)
However there are two roadblocks on my way:

The phone since it has Android 13 It is encrypted, so on recovery i can take a full disk clone but cannot access my files
Powered on the device is obviously using the disk so i cannot pull an image if it is being used.

So, how i can make a carbon copy of my phone but decrypted? Like i just double click an .img in my linux pc and just browse the files?
With my very limited knowledge on mobile architecture i have 2 guesses how can this be done:

Extract the entire disk encrypted, Then i turn it on and extract the "key" to decrypt it, leveraging my root access if possible.
Mount it like a USB hard drive when powered on, and "decrypted" (yes that i know physically is still encrypted and decrypts onto ram on the fly or something along those lines) and make an image with dd, gparted, gnome-disks, etc.

But I might be just way off, so I'm open to try anything...

Does your phone use FDE or FBE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195713/2241

FBE: getprop ro.crypto.type -->
file

FBE seems the case bc on twrp the i see the same amount of files as when on the file manager but with the names (and probably the content) garbled
