# Is the Samsung Galaxy S9 encrypted by default or can it be encrypted?

Tags: samsung, encryption

Basically, I travel a lot with my phone and having it encrypted would be very useful in knowing that a crook wouldn't be able to gain access to my data should my phone be stolen.

I heard from one source stating that all devices running Android 6.0+ must be encrypted by default in order to be certified.

However, I also heard from a Samsung representative that they removed the option to encrypt the internal storage after Android 7.0.

What's the actual case?

Comment: It has to be encrypted by default. What the Samsung rep refers to is probably by removing the choice the option to encrypt is not left to user (being default). You can check yourself  device encryption status as mentioned here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96125/131553

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are seeing correct sources on both accounts.

Android 6.0 made it compulsory if you are using Google Play Protect, this will show Certified Device in Google Play, You open the Play Store and go to settings, then scroll to the bottom, it will show you the certified status - therefore the encryption status.

It makes sense to remove the obsolete option past that point.. Android 7.0.

It may have been an unintentional oversight or the developers still required the option to automatically return true.