# Android 9 pie see if device is encrypted

Tags: security, settings, encryption, 9.0-pie, disk-encryption

I am trying to figure out if my Android (Pie) is encrypted.

Per [Is there a way for a user to tell if their Android device is encrypted or not?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96125/315857), it says my phone will be reported as `phone encrypted`.

However, when I go `Settings` --> `Lock screen & security` --> `Encryption & credentials`, here is what I can see:

> [image: Encryption & credentials screen]

One can see that:

- My SD card is encrypted
- Credential protection: `Hardware-backed`

I see no mention of `phone encrypted`.

Does this mean my phone's contents (not my SD card) is actually encrypted?

---

**My Phone Specifics**

- LG-G710VM (aka LG G7 ThinQ for Verizon)
- Android 9 (Pie)
- Secure start-up is enabled

---

****2/24/2020 Edit****

In an answer below, @beeshyams suggested verifying encryption by following the answer to this question: [How can I find out if my device uses FBE or FDE?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195713/315857)

Using [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) I ran `getprop ro.crypto.type`.

It output: `block`, which means my device uses Full Disk Encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All devices that run Android 5 and beyond (out of the box) are encrypted. That's probably why you don't see a separate status for device encryption as you see for Ext.SD.

Encryption can be [Full-Disk Encryption (FDE)](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/Full-Disk)  or [File-Based Encryption (FBE)](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based). The device is encrypted on first boot using default encryption and once the user sets up lock screen mechanism , that is used for encryption. Relevant extracts

> - FDE was introduced in Android 4.4 and is supported till Android 9.
> - Android 7.0 and higher supports file-based encryption (FBE).
> - For devices running Android 7.0–8.1, file-based encryption can't be used together with adoptable storage.
> - Devices running Android 9 and higher can use adoptable storage and file-based encryption
>
> > - For new devices running Android 10 and higher, file-based encryption is required.

Your device being Android 9 with secure start up, it's most likely FBE. You can verify `ro.crypto.type` on Terminal Emulator and it would show `file` ( See [How can I find out if my device uses FBE or FDE?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195713/131553))

Comment: Thank you @beeshyams!  Turns out my device uses `FDE`, see my edit to my question.  I am surprised, even with secure start-up enabled, it's not `FBE`.  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer with "Secure start-up" turned on, your lock screen password is used for decryption. It doesn't switch between FDE/FBE. Encryption type is decided at the time of ROM development.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I purchased my ThinQ as a refurbished phone.  In that case, would ROM development have been done at the factory where the phone was made?  (I am not very familiar with Android)

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer yes stock ROMs are developed by OEM. But for many devices it's possible to have custom ROMs which can be developed, improved and modified by any developer.

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer I wrongly *guessed* it to be FBE (used *likely*). This should not matter to your query whether the device is encrypted. As Irfan pointed out OEMs decide

Comment: Try with `getprop ro.crypto.state`, if knowing whether the phone is encrypted is enough for you.

Comment: @beeshyams OP ran `getprop ro.crypto.type`, not `getprop ro.crypto.state`.

Comment: @beeshyams I noticed the answer in that link, yes. Still, OP seems to have tried the "pretty way", not your answer's "better way".