# How to Secure a Android Device that has been Rooted and have Unlocked Bootloader

Tags: root-access, security, android-11

I'm Talking about securing my data against everyone.(Thieves, Police, Friends etc etc)
I'm pretty sure my device have encryption enabled on internal storage,(how can I check that?)
also I have a 6 digit pin code on the lock screen. Running Android 11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I view files from "Internal Storage" WITHOUT entering password either in OrangeFox recovery or via USB cable on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241934/why-can-i-view-files-from-internal-storage-without-entering-password-either-in)

Comment: as we have learned recently there is no way to check and no setting we can trust other than locked bootloader (see chat). Try to decrypt from custom recovery that might give you some idea how safe your device is