# Recover user data (photos videos) from a Poco X3 Pro forgotten pattern

Tags: data-recovery, xiaomi, locked-out, pattern-lock, development

So, I decided yesterday to change my pattern to something more complicated for terms of privacy. For my bad, I had such an awful day yesterday and I honestly don't remember the whole pattern. My fingerprint is also registered on the device, but it won't use it since I have my pattern set too. The related Google account and Mi account belong to me, and I have the users/passwords.

I've been taking pictures and videos for over a year without syncing in the cloud (dumb me, really). I've been trying to find my pattern by drawing what I remember for almost eight hours. I have an important amount of information that I care in my phone, like a concert I went with my brother and so on.

Initially my personal computer had the usb-debugging allowed and I tried some stuff with `adb`, like trying to pull my `gesture.key` from my device for trying a brute-force attack for my pattern, but I was unable get my key since my phone is not rooted. I also tried to pull all my personal data from `adb` but I needed to grant the permissions from my device, which I couldn't do.

I downloaded some of those trash-software that promise you to get away the pattern (by deleting the data, which is something that I don't want to do) and constantly updated my usb drivers it seems like in some point my PC got unauthorized for the usb debugging. So, some of the `adb` stuff that I could try is discarded now.

I also tried to boot in recovery mode (stock recovery) and activated the safe assistant mode, but the mi desktop software did not recognise my phone. I tried to boot some custom recovery, but I don't have my bootloader unlocked. I took my phone to different mobile care centers, and they told me that only way to get away the pattern is by deleting my data, which again is something that **I don't want to happen**.

For now, I'm trying different patterns that kind of come in mind and registering theme to keep track of those which are not the right ones.

I'm desperate and running out of ideas. I'm a developer with knowledge on C, C++, JavaScript, TypeScript, Python and some others, so any developer-approaches are welcome. Also, I'm willing to offer rewards or pay for overcoming this.

My Device is a Xiaomi Poco X3 Pro.

Comment: Most likely you will lose all data, but worth a try: flash [eng firmware](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4391999) to get adb root access. if you are lucky your device comes with [broken encryption](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241934) and don't need pattern

Comment: This seems like the extreme solution I was looking for. Thank you so much for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Xiaomi phones doesn't support you to transfer the data of a locked out device as it can be used by anyone if found a lost phone. You can try the forgot password option on the phone and change it through the mi account if it supports that. Or you can check if it's backed in the mi cloud using the same account and checking on your device. You can always contact the mi service centre's nearby for further informations.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I think it describes what I already know and tried.